# identityserver4 saves device ip?

Tags: identityserver4

I use IdentityServer4 and Xamarin.Forms. All work fine. But there is a question. When i log in and then exit the mobile application or re-build then, when I log in again, I automatically log in! Without asking for a username and password!

I want to note, I did not log out in IdentityServer, just closed app.

It seems that the server remembers the ip address of the application, and if a request for authorization repeatedly arrives from it, without prior log out, then it automatically log in.

This is my guess. I did not find it in the documentation. And did not find the corresponding records in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the cookie based authentication scheme that is set up on your Identity Server 4. You are logging in through your device browser client so after the user logs in the cookie is left and thus the skip of login screen next time there is an attempt to log in.

Comment: Ooo!!Definitely! Cookie!!I Forgot about them!